# Ошибка: "Вызвано срабатывание точки останова"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector, struct

Имеется программа: считывает данные из файла в строку, парсит ее по ";", записывает в строковый вектор, затем преобразует данные в тип double и записывает в вектор-структуру значения. Программа выдает ошибку. Посмотрел по отладчику: ошибка вылетает в конце первого прохода цикла for. Что за ошибка и как я могу ее исправить?
Спасибо

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;


struct pointXY
{
double x;
double y;
};

pointXY *dot;

int main()
{
dot = new pointXY;
ifstream file("poly.txt");
vector<string> vals;
if (file.is_open()) {
    string s;
    int counter1 = 0;
    while (getline(file, s, ';'))
    {
        vals.push_back(s);
    }
    file.close();
    vector<pointXY> pgn;
    for (int i = 1; i < vals.size(); i += 2) {
        dot->x = atof(vals[i - 1].c_str());
        dot->y = atof(vals[i].c_str());
        pgn.push_back(*dot);
        cout << pgn[i - 1].x << " - " << pgn[i].y << endl;
    }
}
else{
    cout << "Open error!";
}
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: assert - это не точка остановки, а срабатывание проверки (assertion - перев. защита, оператор контроля, ОТК). Чаще всего assert проверяет на выход параметров функции/массива/обьекта за пределы допустимых диапазонов (out of range - за пределами диапазона), например, если с массива запрашивается елемент №5 при размере массива 3.

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Во первых есть функция `stod`  для преобразования  `std::string в double`

Во вторых, вы можете сразу инициализировать поля структуры списком инициализации.

А вот главное, у вас ошибка при выводе. Вы кладете в вектор один элемент, а хотите прочитать  два. Чтобы было все правильно, просто нужно прочитать последный элемент вектора `pgn`.

```
 for (size_t i = 1; i < vals.size(); i += 2) {
        const double d1 = stod(vals[i - 1]),
                d2 = stod(vals[i]);
        pgn.push_back({d1, d2});
        cout << pgn.back().x << " - " << pgn.back().y << endl;
    }
```

Так получше(и указатель на структуру вовсе не нужен. Лишняя память и писанина)

Comment: Понял, спасибо большое, исправлю!

Answer (score -2):

Отбой, разобрался. (нужно было добавить строку pgn.push_back(*dot); после каждого присвоения значения dot->x, dot->y).

Comment: У вас последовательность 1;2;3;4 должна преобразоваться в последовательность пар (1,0),(1,2),(3,2),(3,4) ?

Comment: нет, в (1;2) и (3;4)

Comment: А судя по pgn[i - 1].x, pgn[i].y и двум push_back будет именно так как я описал